# How to Automate Backup verification in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, database-administration

I am taking full backup every day, Differential backup after 12 hrs and log backup every 15 minutes.
I want to verify those backups automatically.
I know the command "RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\Test.bak' " but we have to verify it manually one by one. as i have automated backup process. Need to do verification too.
Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com) (and I recommend that you do, as it makes the scheduling and validation of your backups as you've described them here and other maintenance tasks *much* easier to set up and manage), you can have it automatically run `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` after backing up databases by specifying `@Verify='Y'` in the parameters you pass into it.

If you'd like a PowerShell solution, check out the [`dbatools`](https://dbatools.io/) function [`Restore-DbaDatabase`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Restore-DbaDatabase), with the `-VerifyOnly` switch passed in. It will locate the most recent backup of each database (or a specified list of databases) and perform a test of that backup in the way you specify (verify only or, by default, full restore & `DBCC CHECKDB`)